# Can I execute javascript when typing on a form?

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm trying to find a way to trigger JavaScript when writing on an input
Thanks to everyone can help me

```
<input id="tophead-searchbar" class="searchbar" placeholder="Cerca" onfocus="mostraanteprimericerca();" onchange="Result1InnerHTML();">
```

Anyone that can help me?

```
    function Result1InnerHTML() {
        document.getElementById("Result1").innerHTML = "Cerca" + document.getElementById("tophead-searchbar").innerHTML + "su Nevent";
    }
```

This is the function I want to call

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the input as the user types, use the `input` event. This will also catch content which the user pastes in using
the mouse.

Also note that using `onX` attributes in your HTML is no longer good practice and should be avoided. Use unobtrusive event handlers attached within your JS code. This can be done using the `addEventListsner()` method.

Finally, `input` elements don't have any `innerHTML`, you need to read the `value` of the control instead.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#tophead-searchbar');
const output = document.querySelector('#result');

input.addEventListener('input', e => output.innerHTML = `Cerca ${input.value} su Nevent`);
```

```html
<input id="tophead-searchbar" class="searchbar" placeholder="Cerca" />

<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `oninput` event instead of `onchange`